# Copy found result under the current row

Tags: vba, excel

So I am having a worksheet with 16 columns. And I would like to find out the cells with font color is vbRed. Lets say Range("A5") is the found cell then I would like to copy and paste the entire row into the next row in the current worksheet.

As I am writing Macro, I found my program will keep looping on the row that I copied and pasted. And also I am not sure whether I can use loop, copy and paste together with find method. I will strong appreciate if anyone can help with this.

With my current code:

```
Sub CopyRow()

Dim Row As Long
Row = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Row)

For Each cel In rng
If cel.Font.Color = vbRed Then
cel.Rows.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
cel.EntireRow.Copy cel.Offset(-1).EntireRow
cel.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

There's infinite loop....

Comment: We can help you with your code only if you add it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the first cell empty in a column :

```
Range("YOUR COLUMN" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
```

If your column A is always filled, you can base your macro on it and then paste the entire row you copied.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim SrchRngA as range

Set SrchRngA = Range("a16:a500")


For Each cel In SrchRngA
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "AB") > 0 Then 'search for "AB"
        cel.offset(1,0).value = cel.value 'replace next row with current cell value
    end if
next cel
```